# Moving Windows 7 Licence to Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-activation

I have bought a new computer with Windows 7 Pro pre-installed on it. As I need to use Linux I have used this tool [Advanced token manager](http://joshcellsoftwares.com/products/advancedtokensmanager/) to backup my product key. Then I have replaced the OS with Linux so I can then install my Windows 7 back again within the primary Linux OS as VM but I wasn't able to use the same product key as getting the error 0XC004E003.I'm not sure about the licensing system for MS but it looks to me as MS still thinks that the Key is being used on a different machine and I'm not sure how to change this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the preinstalled licenses are somehow connected to the hardware. Anyways Windows Desktop Operating systems can be virtualized only with a Volume license [see here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/learn-more/brief-windows-virtual-machine.aspx), so this usage would not be legal. Why didn't you setup dual boot or updated to Windows 10 and use the Ubuntu bash subsystem? Or put Windows 7 back on the hardware and use Linux in a VM (hyper-v or virtualbox).

Comment: @Zina Well the good news is that at least I didn't lose my license completely as it sounds like I would be able to reinstall Windows 7 on the hard drive. Unfortunately that wouldn't be useful for me as I need to use Linux as my main OS. In fact the only reason I need windows as VM is to be able to sync files my iPhone (using iTunes on Windows). Thanks for your help Zina

Comment: @Zina BTW would I still be able to upgrade to Windows 10?. Even though  my usage depends on Linux, I thought that its no longer possible to upgrade Win 7 to 10 without buying an upgrade license?

Comment: Hm, probably no upgrade any more. Not sure. A dual boot (Win7 + Linux) could work for you if you don't sync your iPhone too often. Or maybe {this can help}(https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31322).

Comment: @Faisal - You can upgrade to Windows 10 provided you purchased a license to Windows 10.  You can an entire year to upgrade to Windows 10 for free, that period of time, ended on July 29th 2016.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have the licence and the free upgrade licence has ended according to MS. I don't think its worth the upgrade cost for me to I don't manly use it.

Comment: I have an error in my comment i siad can insteadof can't

Comment: If you search the web for **iTunes Ubuntu**, or whatever your Linux distribution is, you will find lots of advice about running it in Linux and alternative approaches. Personally, I found iTunes for Windows a pretty awful piece of software, and I now happily support my iPad from Ubuntu by plugging it into a USB port and copying media files to and from it as a USB disc. You have to learn which iOS directories to use, but after that it's quick and painless. I haven't tried it, but I don't see why you shouldn't autosync the relevant iOS directories with copies on your laptop.

Comment: @AFH I found that there is no way to run iTunes on Linux thats why I was using a windows VM. I can copy images only with USB. If there is a way to copy other media ? Do you have a link? I use Linux Mint anything with on Ubuntu should work for me.

Comment: I searched for "itunes for linux mint 17" (at Google's suggestion, while I was typing) and the first result was [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJ4dWJbF4jk). I don't expect much has changed in later Mint releases. It's not clear how many of the iTunes facilities work, but it certainly loads. Another search suggestion was "linux mint itunes alternatives", and this is worth your investigation.